# college touchdown rules for endzone catches

Tags: rules, american-football, collegiate

If the player catches the football after he runs behind the line at the back of the endzone is it a touchdown? Is he out of bounds?

Comment: Is the player still beyond the line when they catch the ball, or have they come back into the field of play?

Answer (score 1):

**Not eligible** (no touchdown)

Exceptions:

1. If they are pushed out and immediately come back into the endzone. (Touchdown if they catch it in bounds)
2. If the defense touched the pass first (generally everyone is an eligible receiver after that). (Touchdown if they catch it in bounds).

Source: NCAA 2023 Football Rules, Rule 7, section 3, article 4.

P.S. in case this is the question: The end line out the back of the endzone is the same as going out of bounds on a sideline. Caught there is out of bounds.  If they go out on their own and come back, it is illegal touching.